# Share Canvas as image using FabricJS

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, facebook-share, todataurl

My Fabric canvas has a image as the background and another image from a url within the canvas.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('resultCanvas');

 canvas.setBackgroundImage('someUrl/background.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
        backgroundImageOpacity: 0.5,
        backgroundImageStretch: false
    });

 fabric.Image.fromURL('someUrl/image.jpg', function (oImg) {
        oImg.left(100).oImg.top(100);
        canvas.add(oImg);
    });
```

Now I need to make this canvas an image to share on facebook.

I have tried toDataUrl() function from fabricJS at a click of a button, but it gives a blank image.

```
canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'jpeg',
        quality: 0.8
    });
```

Even the save as image function you get when right clicked on the canvas in Chrome gives a blank image.

I tried serializing it to a JSON and SVG but they also gives a blank canvas. I also tried uploading the image data to the server via ajax and saving it as a image on the server. There also I get a blank image on the server.

However if I changed the FabricJS canvas to a static canvas as shown below everything works. It comes as an image when you do save as image on chrome.

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('resultCanvas');

//instead of 

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('resultCanvas');
```

So what should I do to make it work on a regular canvas because I need the interactivity functionality of FabricJS.

Comment: And you don't have a message in the console saying that the operation is insecure or that the canvas has been tainted? If so, this is a CORS issue. Otherwise, are you sure you don't call `toDataURL` before the asynchronous `setBackgroundImage` and `fromURL` are performed ?

Comment: I am using the images to load from the same domain so it shouldn't be a problem right? If its something to do with asynchronous method calls why is it working for StaticCanvas.

Comment: One suggestion in relation StaticCanvas is use the PHP,  on click `button share` change `fabric.Canvas` to `fabric.StaticCanvas` or with jquery variables

Answer (score 0):

When you use toDataUrl, aren't you supposed to pass in a Base64 data url?  Something that looks like this: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA..."